# mysql_? equivalent of PDO's prepare() and execute()

Tags: mysql, pdo

One of my hosting server does not support PDO. Are there and `mysql_` commands which does the same function of PDO's `prepare()` and `execute()`?

I am looking for the parameter substitution feature, i.e. `VALUES (?, ?)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysqli`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php